# Java keystore expiry beyond 30 years

Tags: java, keystore

I want to create a Java keystore and would like the expiry date to be beyond 2035. Is it possible to set the expiry time beyond 30 years?

Thanks

Comment: I donno how to do that but congrats on thinking ahead!

Comment: Why? This seems like an odd requirement.

Comment: Well the requirement is actually to provide a keystore that never expires.

Comment: "that never expires" No product lasts forever; not even software that never "wears out". I assert that any requirement that requires a software product to operate longer than its "planned lifetime" is wrong, and that any software product that does not have a specified lifetime has a missing requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could by altering the number you use to generate the keystore, but why would you want to? This seems like a terrible idea from a security perspective.

EXAMPLE keytool -genkey -alias myjavakey -keyalg RSA -validity 3650

WOULD BE MORE LIKE keytool -genkey -alias myjavakey -keyalg RSA -validity 36500

or something similar. I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: +1 I think the question that comes to my mind is, what do you think is the likelihood that (a) your software is still actually running, unmodified, and not updated 30 years from now, and (b) that you wouldn't think to update it or set a reminder between now and then?

Comment: @normalocity Thanks. Well very unlikely but as I mentioned further up the intention is avoid having to regularly generate keystores.

Comment: Well my answer should work for you, but did you tell you client / employer about the dangers of this?

Comment: @Raj I would have the same question. I understand the need and pressure that come from client requirements, but there are good reasons to have expiring key stores, and as the technical expert you really should bring these up. If you've had that conversation with them already, and they're aware of the dangers but decided to ignore them, then maybe you're covered, but it's still bad practice. Anyhow, I won't delve much deeper, since I trust you're a professional, and you're the best one to answer this question since you're the one in the situation, and I'm an observer.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about the certs being used publicly or in a B2B capacity. Sometimes PKI is used internally to authenticate access between systems. With restrictive file access to the keystore and proper command auditing, it can be an effective way to secure sub-system. In these cases re-issuing certificates can often increase exposure especially if the process is not well defined nor automated. In such cases, unsigned PKI fine, but Java keystores insist on certs.